# How do I create a PDF out of a custom object?

Tags: pdf

I got a Custom Object "Visit Report" with related lists like Attendees, Open Activities, Activity History. 
I would like to get a PDF file out of all these data that could be send to the Customer finally.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to create a custom Visualforce page with all of the information that you'd like to send to the customer.

You can then render the Visualforce page into a pdf using the following parameter in the top of the Visualforce page.

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
```

More information converting a Page to a PDF is available [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm)

This method also allows you to customize the look and feel of the PDF